# How to connect react with server API? (Ideally by creating custom hook)

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-hooks

I am trying to call server apis from `useEffect`, as recommended from [React - How get initial value from Backend API in useState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940965/react-how-get-initial-value-from-backend-api-in-usestate), but also, another `useEffect` for updating the server, but the updating part does not work:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

// custom hook used throughout the codebase
export default function useCartItems(initialValue) {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(initialValue ?? []);

  // initial state setup (cannot use in useState, since axios return promise and useState does not wait, so must be done once in useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/items-quantity')
      .then(res => setCartItems(res.data));
  }, []);

  // saving state on every state change
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/items-quantity', cartItems)
  }, [cartItems]);

  return [cartItems, setCartItems];
}
```

but the "update" `useEffect` (with `[cartItems]`) updates it every time, so the JSON sent to the server is wrong (the JSON is not recreated and just appends data and empty arrays). Is there a way how to achieve the loading and **recreating** the state that will be send to the server - saving to the server (basically mimicking react state management) by a custom hook? Or how is the react-server communication usually done?

PS: to show a working custom hook. Before I tried to make communication between react and server, I was saving data simply in local storage. The hook is as:

```
export default function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const json = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (json != null) {
      return JSON.parse(json);
    }
    if (typeof initialValue === 'function') {
      return initialValue();
    } else {
      return initialValue;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value])

  return [value, setValue];
}
```

and this works correctly. So I want to achieve similar hook with axios.

The object updated via axios post is wrong:

```json
"items-quantity": [

    {
      "items-quantity": [ 
        {
          "id": 1,
          "quantity": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "quantity": 1
        },
        [],
        [],
        [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "quantity": 3
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ],
        [],
        [],
        [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "quantity": 3
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "quantity": 1
          },
          [],
          [],
          [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "quantity": 3
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "quantity": 1
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
```

so the object is just adding to it. not **recreating it**. Also I don't know why there are any empty arrays. The correct object send to the server should be just this:

```
{
  "items": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "quantity": 3
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "quantity": 1
}
]
}
```

nothing else. The object added by `setCartItems` is in form of:

> {id: `some number`, "quantity": `some number`}.

That's all. So the object above object is clearly wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "the "update" useEffect (with [cartItems]) updates it everytime, so the json sent to the server is wrong". How is it wrong?

Comment: @WilomGfx see updates

Comment: useEffect is not meant to be used like that. You should be calling your update api in an event listener. Expose a function from the hook, and call it instead of using an effect

Comment: @nullptr "expose a function from the hook, and call it instead of useEffect`, well thats what `useState` does (exposing a `set...` function to be used). But I have written that `useState` cannot be used here, because the initial value to be set is promise (getting the initial data from server as `axios.get(url)` is promise but useState does not wait -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375517/usestate-with-async-function-returning-promise-pending. So must be used inside useEffect

Comment: you misunderstood me. this is not a very hard problem either way. I suggest you google it. also have a look at "You might not need an effect" in the react docs.